# Add on package for an app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How can I create a new package as an add on for my app. For instance. I have a photo app with some images. I need to add some more images to my app. How do I create another app package which will install the images in my app. I know I will have to make a new release but for future, adding more images will be very easy. This way I can create multiple packages and users can download the package they like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your application, increment the version number and release it as an update.

If you want to sell update "packages" for money you should look into the [in app purchase](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) model.

As you are dealing with images, you are probably best downloading the images from a server and storing them in a directory within the application sandbox. Then load the images for local use from there.